# Using N more than once in a computation

Tags: numerics, approximation

So I'm trying to enter a function that computes Pi to the nth place divided by Pi to the mth place, so to do that I started with actual numerical values.
I tried

```
(N[Pi, 3])/(N[Pi, 2])
```

but that just gave the result of 1.

However 3.14/3.1 = 1.0129

No matter what I put in for the precision on either, I always get 1. Can I not use more than 1 N in a computation? How would I go about this??

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use Round

```
Round[Pi, 0.01]/Round[Pi, 0.1]

1.0129
```

or you could use `Floor` depending on exactly what you wish to calculate. The reason it doesn't work with `N` is because `N` just change the way the number is displayed, it doesn't actually change the value. Consider `n1 = N[Pi, 2]` which looks like `3.1`. But if you type `FullForm[n1]` you will see that it is really `Pi` expressed with only 2 digits of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica follows standard significant figure rules. The computation  carries all known decimal places then round up at the end of the computation according to significant figure present in each operation. Therefore using the expression N  does not alter the number of significant figures of Pi.